# how to generate light and pastel colors randomly in android?

Tags: java, android, colors

I want to set background color to my layout, color must be generated randomly,
till now i am using this code to generate colors but the colors are so dark, but i don't want these dark colors, need only light and pastel colors.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
    int r = rnd.nextInt(155) + 100; // 128 ... 255
    int g = rnd.nextInt(155) + 010; // 128 ... 255
    int b = rnd.nextInt(155) + 001; // 128 ... 255

    int clr = Color.rgb(r, g, b);
```

Comment: Save the `RGB` values of the colors that you would like to have in an array or something. Than randomly pick a value from that array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't understand why you add different numbers to each channel. Currently the result would be that you generate primarily red colors.

Also if you put a leading `0` in front of a number it is interpreted as an [**octal number**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). In other words it is interpreted as base 8.

So `010` would actually be an octal number and the decimal equivalent is counter intuitively `8`. The same goes for `001`, but in that case the octal number is the same as the decimal one. `1` in octal is equivalent to `1` in decimal.

Additionally you don't use a seed for your `Random` instance. This is pretty bad because it means that you will always generate the exactly same colors. You need to use a seed from a sufficiently random source like `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

---

But let's get to the point:

You can generate random pastel colors by randomly picking values for each channel and then mixing it with either white or with another pastel color. Try something like this:

```
final Random mRandom = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public int generateRandomColor() {
    // This is the base color which will be mixed with the generated one
    final int baseColor = Color.WHITE;

    final int baseRed = Color.red(baseColor);
    final int baseGreen = Color.green(baseColor);
    final int baseBlue = Color.blue(baseColor);

    final int red = (baseRed + mRandom.nextInt(256)) / 2;
    final int green = (baseGreen + mRandom.nextInt(256)) / 2;
    final int blue = (baseBlue + mRandom.nextInt(256)) / 2;

    return Color.rgb(red, green, blue);
}
```

You can pick a light grey as base color, or some other pastel color you like. You should probably not pick white as base color since then the generated colors tend to be to light for white text to be easily visible. Try slightly darker shades or for the best result some pastel color you like.

Comment: I don't understand what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: I am getting very light i will change the constants but you know some brightness umm i am going add a pictures or a question ref.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7816543/how-to-create-pastel-colors-programmatically-in-c) need colors like this image so the white text could seen easiliy

Comment: thank you for that. @Xaver Kapeller  But in this question's ref please[look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707277/background-color-or-images-shuffling-on-scrolling-in-recyclerview)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution for generating almost white, but never white colors is:

```
final int base = 255,
                min = 26,
                max = 35;
final int red = base - random(min, max);
final int green = base - random(min, max);
final int blue = base - random(min, max);

int color = Color.rgb(red, green, blue);
```

with this method to create a random int (random variable is definded as `public static final Random random = new Random();` earlier)

```
//min and max inclusive
public static int random(int min, int max) {
   if(min >= max)
       throw new RuntimeException("min is >= max!");

   return random.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
}
```

You can edit the min and max values for a different rage of random colors.